# How to pivot and calculate percentages in t-sql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a table that looks like this:

```
    DECLARE @myTable TABLE (country varchar(max), code int)  
    INSERT @myTable
    SELECT 'A', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A', 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A', 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B', 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C', 1 ;
```

I want to pivot off the A/B/C and then count the number of 2s and have the percentage of the total the 2 is.

I can get the number of 2s with this query

```
    DECLARE @mySecondTable TABLE (country varchar(max), code int);
    INSERT @mySecondTable
       SELECT * FROM @myTable 
       WHERE code=2;

    SELECT [A], [B], [C]
    FROM
     (SELECT Country, code
      FROM @mySecondTable) AS source
    PIVOT
    (
      COUNT(code)
      FOR Country IN ([A], [B], [C]) ) AS pvt;
```

But I really want it to look like this:

```
    A          B         C
  2 (40.0%)   1 (20.0%)  0
```

How do I get the totals and calculate the percentages ?

Thanks!

Comment: The solution you accepted does not return the correct result:(

Comment: Hi John,  I got locked out for some reason.  Here was my comment. Hi Lamak,  That uses the wrong total to make the percentages.  For A I need a total of 5 so the percentages of the total that are 2 = 2/5=40% For B it would be 1/5=20%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE (country varchar(max), code int)  
    INSERT @myTable
    SELECT 'A', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A', 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A', 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B', 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C', 1 ;

    DECLARE @mySecondTable TABLE (country varchar(10), pct varchar(20), code int);
    INSERT @mySecondTable
       SELECT country
       , pct=cast(count(*)over(partition by country,code) as varchar(10))
            +' ('+cast(100*
                cast(count(*)over(partition by country,code)as decimal(3,2))
                / CAST(count(*)over(partition by country) as decimal(3,2)) as varchar(10))
            +'%)'
       , code
       FROM @myTable

    SELECT [A], [B], [C]
    FROM
     (SELECT Country, pct
      FROM @mySecondTable
      WHERE code=2
      ) AS source
    PIVOT
    (
      MAX(pct)
      FOR Country IN ([A], [B], [C]) ) AS pvt;
```

Result:

[image]